# react native facebook login gives the error cannot get auth/facebook

Tags: react-native

hello i am not much familiar with react-native and i started developing facebook login using passport and express js in react native.

i implemented the code for that but when i click on Login with facebook it will open browser and gives the error

cannot get auth/facebook

my url is http://localhost:8081/auth/facebook as valid Oauth redirect url

I dont know how to put valid Url in valid Oauth redirect url in facebook developer console also

i have created backend folder in my project and created config.js server.js file

my server.js is as follows

```
    import express from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import FacebookStrategy from 'passport-facebook';
import GoogleStrategy from 'passport-google-oauth20';
// Import Facebook and Google OAuth apps configs
import { facebook, google } from './config';

// Transform Facebook profile because Facebook and Google profile objects look different
// and we want to transform them into user objects that have the same set of attributes
const transformFacebookProfile = (profile) => ({
  name: profile.name,
  avatar: profile.picture.data.url,
});

// Transform Google profile into user object
const transformGoogleProfile = (profile) => ({
  name: profile.displayName,
  avatar: profile.image.url,
});

// Register Facebook Passport strategy
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(facebook,
  // Gets called when user authorizes access to their profile
  async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)
    // Return done callback and pass transformed user object
    => done(null, transformFacebookProfile(profile._json))
));

// Register Google Passport strategy
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(google,
  async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)
    => done(null, transformGoogleProfile(profile._json))
));

// Serialize user into the sessions
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user));

// Deserialize user from the sessions
passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user));

// Initialize http server
const app = express();

// Initialize Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


// Set up Facebook auth routes
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/auth/facebook' }),
  // Redirect user back to the mobile app using Linking with a custom protocol OAuthLogin
  (req, res) => res.redirect('OAuthLogin://login?user=' + JSON.stringify(req.user)));

// Set up Google auth routes
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));

app.get('/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/auth/google' }),
  (req, res) => res.redirect('OAuthLogin://login?user=' + JSON.stringify(req.user)));

// Launch the server on the port 3000
const server = app.listen(8081, () => {
  const { address, port } = server.address();
  console.log(`Listening at http://${address}:${port}`);
});
```

and my config .js is as follws

```
export const facebook = {
clientID: 'MY CLIENT ID',
clientSecret: 'MY CLIENT SECRET',
callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8081/auth/facebook/callback',
profileFields: ['id', 'name', 'displayName', 'picture', 'email'],
};
```

export const google = {
   clientID: 'MY CLIENT ID',
   clientSecret: 'MY CLIENT SECRET',
   callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8081/auth/google/callback',
   };

and my package .json is as follows

```
  {
    "name": "backend",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "start": "node node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js -- node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js server.js"
      },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "^6.23.0",
      "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
      "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
      "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
      "express": "^4.15.3",
      "passport": "^0.3.2",
      "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
      "passport-google-oauth20": "^1.0.0"
    }
  }
```

I need to know that how to put valid localhost url at developer console and in app also.

and how to solve that cannot get auth/facebook error

Answer (score 0):

Use Facebook SDK for React Native https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk. All you'll have to do is install this SDK:

```
react-native install react-native-fbsdk
```

Then link it to react native project:

```
react-native link react-native-fbsdk
```

Once you set it up as instructed in repo, implement login with facebook as below-

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
   LoginButton,
   AccessToken
} = FBSDK;

var Login = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
     return (
       <View>
         <LoginButton
           publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
           onLoginFinished={
             (error, result) => {
               if (error) {
                 alert("login has error: " + result.error);
               } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                 alert("login is cancelled.");
               } else {
                 AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                  (data) => {
                     alert(data.accessToken.toString())
                  }
               )
             }
          }
        }
        onLogoutFinished={() => alert("logout.")}/>
     </View>
   );
 }
 });
```

That's it, You should be able to login!